# Putting space between components in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a `JPanel` that contains two `JToggleButtons`. The panel has a `GridBagLayout` and has 1 row and 2 columns. Buttons are located in the same row, but different columns.

```
class UserInterfacePanel extends JPanel {
         private JToggleButton startButton;
         private JToggleButton stopButton;

         public UserInterfacePanel()  {
           setup();
        }
         private void setup()  {
             setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
             GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

             setupButtons();
             //setupButtonsActions();

             c.insets=new Insets(3,3,3,3);
             c.weightx=0.5; //c.weightx=0.0;
             c.weighty=0.5; //c.weighty=0.5;

             c.gridx=0;
             c.gridy=0;
             add(startButton, c);

             c.gridx=1;
             c.gridy=0;
             add(stopButton, c);
       }
            private void setupButtons()  {
                startButton=new JToggleButton(iconStartButton);
                stopButton=new JToggleButton(iconStopButton);
 }

public class UserInterface extends JFrame  {  
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
                run();
        }
        public UserInterface()  {
                setup();
        }

        private void setup()  {
            width=800;
            height=600;

            panel=new UserInterfacePanel();
            getContentPane().add(panel);

            setSize(width, height);
           }
         public static void run()  {
            UserInterface gui=new UserInterface();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

I want to be able to control the spacing between the buttons, but changin `c.gridwidth` or `c.weightx` doesn't give me results. Setting `c.wightx` to 0.0 results in the buttons being too close to each other, while anything other than zero results in them being too far away, with no difference in distance between `c.widthx=0.9` and `c.widthx=0.1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) It's probably [`GridBagConstraints.insets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#insets), [`ipadx`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#ipadx) or [`ipady`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#ipadx) that needs setting. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, I edited the post, it should be runnable now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try making an `Insets` variable, with `int`s that increase every time a button is clicked. Code below:

```
public class UserInterfacePanel extends JPanel {
    private JToggleButton startButton;
    private JToggleButton stopButton;
    private int top = 3, left = 3, bottom = 3, right = 3;
    private Insets i = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);

    public UserInterfacePanel()  {
        setup();
    }

    private void setup()  {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        setupButtons();
        setupButtonsActions();

        c.insets = i;
        c.weightx=0.5; //c.weightx=0.0;
        c.weighty=0.5; //c.weighty=0.5;

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        add(startButton, c);

        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=0;
        add(stopButton, c);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("+1");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                i = new Insets(top+1, left+1, bottom+1, right+1);
                c.insets = i;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        add(b1, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

        //...
    }
```